# Smalltalk array manipulaton

Tags: arrays, class, oop, object, smalltalk

I am new in using smalltalk and i am trying to iterate an array inside an array and evaluate each array member if it is divisible by 4 if true it will return the byte array containing the element using select method
Here's my code:

```
| anArray result |
anArray := #(#(1 2 3 3 4 6 7) #(6 7 6 9 9 4 7 6) #(11 12 13 14 15 14)).
anArray select: [ :each | 
     each do: [ :ea | 
         ea \\ 4 == 0 ifTrue: [ Transcript show: each printString ]
     ]
]
```

The problem is that it needs a boolean condition in the `select` method. Do you know other ways to use select method to return the said output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Smalltalk! Your question is a bit ambiguous. Do you want to select each inner array where any element is divisible by 4? If so, try the following:

```
| anArray result |
anArray := #(#(1 2 3 3 4 6 7) #(6 7 6 9 9 4 7 6) #(11 12 13 14 15 14)).
anArray select: [ :eachArray | 
    eachArray anySatisfy: [ :eachElement | 
        eachElement \\ 4 == 0.
    ].
].
```

Or do you want to print each element from the inner array that is divisible by 4? If so, try the following:

```
| anArray result |
anArray := #(#(1 2 3 3 4 6 7) #(6 7 6 9 9 4 7 6) #(11 12 13 14 15 14)).
anArray do: [ :eachArray | 
    eachArray do: [ :eachElement |
        eachElement \\ 4 == 0 ifTrue: [
            Transcript cr; show: eachElement.
        ].
    ].
].
```

Answer (score 3):

(Read [James Foster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57764706/4081336) first)

If you want to select and print:

```
anArray select: [:eachArray | 
  (eachArray anySatisfy: [:eachElement | eachElement \\ 4 == 0])
      ifTrue: [Transcript cr; show: eachArray];    "no need to #printString"
      yourself]
```

which forces the `Boolean` resulting from `#anySatisfy:` to be answered by the block.